# Get value of div via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have 2 constantly updating spans with coordinates in them. These spans are updated from a separate js file that someone else wrote that is VERY sensitive to changes.

I can see the spans just fine and they are updating the coordinates just fine, however I need to pass them as variables though in a link. For example, I have a link on page `some.php?var1=[value of constantly updating div1]&var2=[value of constantly updating div2]` that I need the user to be able to click.

I need this link to, when clicked, either gets the value of the spans and submits it to a page handler (`some.php` in this case) or is just constantly updated from the spans.  I've tried to get the innerHTML value of the spans, it doesn't seem to be working though to constantly update them....

Comment: Can you add a listener to the span change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your `<span>` elements have IDs:

```
<span id="var1">(constantly updating)</span>
<span id="var2">(constantly updating)</span>
```

Then just construct a placeholder link:

```
<a href="#" id="link">click me!</a>
```

And the following jQuery should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function() {
        window.location = 'some.php?var1=' + 
            $('#var1').text() + '&var2=' + $('#var2').text();
    });
});
```

You also might want to consider using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the values of your `<span>` elements to make sure they get passed correctly, unless you're always sure that the format of the value is URI-safe.

Comment: my links are actually - http://some.domain/pano/admin/add.php?action=update&pano=9&pID=30&pan=-14.567&tilt=24.722  when I create the links (on page render) via php, I'm echoing a list of these links for lots of products.  I'm assigning the pID, pano, and action when the page is rendered and I've got several dozen links on the page that get drawn.  how do I still pass the other link vars?

Comment: Ethan,  Ive tried your method (while statically assigning my other variables), but it's not passing the info from my 2 spans.

Comment: I corrected it, and its working (I had an extra space on one of my labels and it was borking it all)  now I'm just not sure how to pass my other variables.  I was passing the entire link as some.php?var1=xxx&var2=xxx&pID=XXX[generated at runtime in the while loop]&pano=XXX['generated at runtime in the while loop].  Now I've added my class, update, add, remove and its working, but I don't know how to get my normal variables I usually pass via the href

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking...you should be able to include any variables you want on the link with the technique above.  Just keep concatenating them on the `window.location` string.  If the values need to come from PHP, just insert them using `<?php> echo $whatever <?php>`.

Comment: my href looks like this:   <a href=\"../../../pano/admin/add.php?pano=".$pano."&pID=".$id."\" class="update"> so a generated href example is <a href="../../../pano/admin/add.php?pano=1&pID=12 class="update">  my class="update" references this jquery snippet      $(document).ready(function() {
  <!--Get Update-->
      $('.update').click(function() {
        window.location = '../../admin/add.php?action=update&pID=2&pano=1&pan=' + 
            $('#panData').text() + '&tilt=' + $('#tiltData').text();
     });  how do I pass my other cars to that snippet?

Comment: ok, I got it all sorted with some php on the page render except I still need to pass the pID (it's the only thing I need to pass that isn't already grabbed.  I have the pan, tilt, pano, cat, mode with some php if statements (and yes I realize there are more efficient method of doing that) but I just need to pass this 1 variable from my link that calls the $('.update').click(function() { ... }  how do I pass a variable via the link to this function @ethan brown?

Comment: If you need something passed in on a per-link basis, you can either use `data` attributes, or just call a function with a parameter in the `<a>` element's `onclick` attribute (instead of using `$('.update').click`).  For example, `<a href="#" onclick="return goToLink('myParam');">link</a>`.

Comment: so right now my jq snippet looks like      <!--Get Update-->
      $('.update').click(function() {
        window.location = '../../admin/add.php?action=update&cat=<?php echo $c_id; ?>&mode=<?php echo $mode; ?>&pID=2&pano=<?php echo $pano; ?>&pan=' + 
            $('#panData').text() + '&tilt=' + $('#tiltData').text();
     });    and it's in my head, and my link looks like <a class=\"update\" href=\"#\" data-pID=\"12\">Update</a>  how do I make it pass the pID?

Comment: In your click handler, use `$(this).data('pid')`

Comment: $('.update').click(function() {
        window.location = '../../admin/add.php?action=update&cat=<?php echo $c_id; ?>&mode=<?php echo $mode; ?>&pID=' + $(this).data('pID') + '&pano=<?php echo $pano; ?>&pan=' + $('#panData').text() + '&tilt=' + $('#tiltData').text();
     });
   it's giving me an "undefined" in my results page...

Comment: Yes; this may be browser-dependent, so I would make everything lowercase.

Comment: Ethan answered my question successfully and I thank him immensely!  my jQuery skills are admittedly not the finest but he was superb!  Thank you Ethan!

Answer (score 0):

Use .text() function to fetch the text values from the spans onClick -- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: You may want to expand your answer further than just posting a link.